# Mongo DB error: unknown top level operator: $set; How to upsert this record?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, upsert

I am a beginner with MongoDB. I am using it with node & express. My goal is to "insert" (or "upsert" better said) a new user that's registering on a webpage with the database function creating the "registration_time" on the insert. I was told by others than updateOne() rather than insert() is the best way to achieve this end. Perhaps that was bad advice. So I have the code below, which gives the error "unknown top level operator $set". Ok, with this not working, I thought I would do something involving _id and new ObjectID() to get it working.

```
const registerUser = async (user) => {
  const database = await connect();
  return database.collection('user').updateOne(
    {
      $set: {
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password,
        password_hash: user.password_hash,
      },
    },
    { $currentDate: { registration_time: true } },
    { $upsert: true }
  );
};
```

So then I changed the code to this below (to have Mongo give me an ObjectID on the insert), which got rid of the unknown top level operator $set" error, but give me some other error which I don't know how to interpret.

```
const registerUser = async (user) => {
  const database = await connect();
  return database.collection('user').updateOne(
    { _id: new ObjectID() },
    {
      $set: {
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password,
        password_hash: user.password_hash,
      },
    },
    { $currentDate: { registration_time: true } },
    { $upsert: true }
  );
};
```

I verified on my webpage that the new user was not inserted. Here is the error object (I assume that's what this is). What I am doing wrong?

```
  app:routes:account CommandResult {
  app:routes:account   result: {
  app:routes:account     n: 0,
  app:routes:account     nModified: 0,
  app:routes:account     opTime: { ts: [Timestamp], t: 2 },
  app:routes:account     electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000002,
  app:routes:account     ok: 1,
  app:routes:account     '$clusterTime': { clusterTime: [Timestamp], signature: [Object] },
  app:routes:account     operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1606781586 }
  app:routes:account   },
  app:routes:account   connection: Connection {
  app:routes:account     _events: [Object: null prototype] {
  app:routes:account       commandStarted: [Function],
  app:routes:account       commandFailed: [Function],
  app:routes:account       commandSucceeded: [Function],
  app:routes:account       clusterTimeReceived: [Function]
  app:routes:account     },
  app:routes:account     _eventsCount: 4,
  app:routes:account     _maxListeners: undefined,
  app:routes:account     id: 1,
  app:routes:account     address: '34.123.254.59:27017',
  app:routes:account     bson: BSON {},
  app:routes:account     socketTimeout: 0,
  app:routes:account     host: 'cluster0-shard-00-02.ht4ef.mongodb.net',
  app:routes:account     port: 27017,
  app:routes:account     monitorCommands: false,
  app:routes:account     closed: false,
  app:routes:account     destroyed: false,
  app:routes:account     lastIsMasterMS: 24,
  app:routes:account     [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  app:routes:account     [Symbol(description)]: StreamDescription {
  app:routes:account       address: '34.123.254.59:27017',
  app:routes:account       type: 'RSPrimary',
  app:routes:account       minWireVersion: 0,
  app:routes:account       maxWireVersion: 8,
  app:routes:account       maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216,
  app:routes:account       maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000,
  app:routes:account       maxWriteBatchSize: 100000,
  app:routes:account       compressors: []
  app:routes:account     },
  app:routes:account     [Symbol(generation)]: 0,
  app:routes:account     [Symbol(lastUseTime)]: 500832082,
  app:routes:account     [Symbol(queue)]: Map {},
  app:routes:account     [Symbol(messageStream)]: MessageStream {
  app:routes:account       _readableState: [ReadableState],
  app:routes:account       readable: true,
  app:routes:account       _events: [Object: null prototype],
  app:routes:account       _eventsCount: 7,
  app:routes:account       _maxListeners: undefined,
  app:routes:account       _writableState: [WritableState],
  app:routes:account       writable: true,
  app:routes:account       allowHalfOpen: true,
  app:routes:account       bson: BSON {},
  app:routes:account       maxBsonMessageSize: 67108864,
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(buffer)]: [BufferList]
  app:routes:account     },
  app:routes:account     [Symbol(stream)]: TLSSocket {
  app:routes:account       _tlsOptions: [Object],
  app:routes:account       _secureEstablished: true,
  app:routes:account       _securePending: false,
  app:routes:account       _newSessionPending: false,
  app:routes:account       _controlReleased: true,
  app:routes:account       secureConnecting: true,
  app:routes:account       _SNICallback: null,
  app:routes:account       servername: 'cluster0-shard-00-02.ht4ef.mongodb.net',
  app:routes:account       alpnProtocol: false,
  app:routes:account       authorized: true,
  app:routes:account       authorizationError: null,
  app:routes:account       encrypted: true,
  app:routes:account       _events: [Object: null prototype],
  app:routes:account       _eventsCount: 9,
  app:routes:account       connecting: false,
  app:routes:account       _hadError: false,
  app:routes:account       _parent: null,
  app:routes:account       _host: 'cluster0-shard-00-02.ht4ef.mongodb.net',
  app:routes:account       _readableState: [ReadableState],
  app:routes:account       readable: true,
  app:routes:account       _maxListeners: undefined,
  app:routes:account       _writableState: [WritableState],
  app:routes:account       writable: true,
  app:routes:account       allowHalfOpen: false,
  app:routes:account       _sockname: null,
  app:routes:account       _pendingData: null,
  app:routes:account       _pendingEncoding: '',
  app:routes:account       server: undefined,
  app:routes:account       _server: null,
  app:routes:account       ssl: [TLSWrap],
  app:routes:account       _requestCert: true,
  app:routes:account       _rejectUnauthorized: true,
  app:routes:account       timeout: 0,
  app:routes:account       _peername: [Object],
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(verified)]: true,
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(asyncId)]: 438,
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
  app:routes:account         _idleTimeout: -1,
  app:routes:account         _idlePrev: null,
  app:routes:account         _idleNext: null,
  app:routes:account         _idleStart: 23841,
  app:routes:account         _onTimeout: null,
  app:routes:account         _timerArgs: undefined,
  app:routes:account         _repeat: null,
  app:routes:account         _destroyed: true,
  app:routes:account         [Symbol(refed)]: false,
  app:routes:account         [Symbol(asyncId)]: 441,
  app:routes:account         [Symbol(triggerId)]: 433
  app:routes:account       },
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object],
  app:routes:account       [Symbol(disable-renegotiation)]: true
  app:routes:account     },
  app:routes:account     [Symbol(clusterTime)]: { clusterTime: [Timestamp], signature: [Object] },
  app:routes:account     [Symbol(ismaster)]: {
  app:routes:account       hosts: [Array],
  app:routes:account       setName: 'atlas-qzzelf-shard-0',
  app:routes:account       setVersion: 1,
  app:routes:account       ismaster: true,
  app:routes:account       secondary: false,
  app:routes:account       primary: 'cluster0-shard-00-02.ht4ef.mongodb.net:27017',
  app:routes:account       tags: [Object],
  app:routes:account       me: 'cluster0-shard-00-02.ht4ef.mongodb.net:27017',
  app:routes:account       electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000002,
  app:routes:account       lastWrite: [Object],
  app:routes:account       maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216,
  app:routes:account       maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000,
  app:routes:account       maxWriteBatchSize: 100000,
  app:routes:account       localTime: 2020-12-01T00:13:06.393Z,
  app:routes:account       logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30,
  app:routes:account       connectionId: 590075,
  app:routes:account       minWireVersion: 0,
  app:routes:account       maxWireVersion: 8,
  app:routes:account       readOnly: false,
  app:routes:account       ok: 1,
  app:routes:account       '$clusterTime': [Object],
  app:routes:account       operationTime: [Timestamp]
  app:routes:account     }
  app:routes:account   },
  app:routes:account   message: BinMsg {
  app:routes:account     parsed: true,
  app:routes:account     raw: <Buffer f5 00 00 00 7c 9a 39 06 06 00 00 00 dd 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00 00 00 10 6e 00 00 00 00 00 10 6e 4d 6f 64 69 66 69 65 64 00 00 00 00 00 03 6f 70 ... 195 more bytes>,
  app:routes:account     data: <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00 00 00 10 6e 00 00 00 00 00 10 6e 4d 6f 64 69 66 69 65 64 00 00 00 00 00 03 6f 70 54 69 6d 65 00 1c 00 00 00 11 74 73 00 02 00 00 ... 179 more bytes>,
  app:routes:account     bson: BSON {},
  app:routes:account     opts: { promoteLongs: true, promoteValues: true, promoteBuffers: false },
  app:routes:account     length: 245,
  app:routes:account     requestId: 104438396,
  app:routes:account     responseTo: 6,
  app:routes:account     opCode: 2013,
  app:routes:account     fromCompressed: undefined,
  app:routes:account     responseFlags: 0,
  app:routes:account     checksumPresent: false,
  app:routes:account     moreToCome: false,
  app:routes:account     exhaustAllowed: false,
  app:routes:account     promoteLongs: true,
  app:routes:account     promoteValues: true,
  app:routes:account     promoteBuffers: false,
  app:routes:account     documents: [ [Object] ],
  app:routes:account     index: 229
  app:routes:account   },
  app:routes:account   modifiedCount: 0,
  app:routes:account   upsertedId: null,
  app:routes:account   upsertedCount: 0,
  app:routes:account   matchedCount: 0
  app:routes:account } +1ms
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add new user you have to create new user and need to save that user.

1.according to your schema you need to create a model

```
const User =mongoose.model("collection_name",schema)
```

2.then u can create new user like that & save it

```
const new_user =new User({
//here you can mention user details according to schema
})
//save method return promise so we need to handle it
 new_user.save()
          .then(()=>console.log("success"))
      .catch((err)=>console.log(err.message))
```

Comment: Thanks, Rupesh. I am not familiar with mongoose, it's not what I have been using for this project, I could be learning that down the road though.

 I think I may have solved it though. The problem is that I had "$upsert" rather than "upsert". The latter was is correct. Wish the error messages would have been more helpful, but I appreciate your try.

Answer (score 0):

I put $upsert, not upsert. Problem solved, so now it's corrected. :)

```
const registerUser = async (user) => {
  const database = await connect();
  return database.collection('user').updateOne(
    {
      $set: {
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password,
        password_hash: user.password_hash,
      },
    },
    { $currentDate: { registration_time: true } },
    { upsert: true }
  );
};
```